# Is it possible to print commands instead of rules in snakemake dry run?

Tags: snakemake

Dry runs are a super important functionality of workflow languages. What I am looking at is mostly what would be executed if I run the command and this is exactly what one see when running `make -n`.

However analogical functionality `snakemake -n` prints something like

```
Building DAG of jobs...

rule produce_output:
    output: my_output
    jobid: 0
    wildcards: var=something

Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   produce_output
    1
```

The log contains kind of everything else than commands that get executed. Is there a way how to get command from snakemake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
snakemake -p --quiet -n
```

`-p` for print shell commands
`-n` for dry run
`--quiet` for removing the rest

EDIT 2019-Jan

This solution seems broken for lasts versions of snakemake

Comment: Maybe @vodka knows an answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
snakemake -p -n
```

Avoid the `--quiet` reported in the @eric-c answer, at least in some situations the combination on `-p -n -q` does not print the command executed without `-n`.

Comment: In my snakemake 5.2.2, this also prints rules, input, output etc... which, from what I understood of the question, was not what was asked. I cannot find a way to print only the shell commands !